# Not getting legend and grid on pyplot/matplotlib figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am drawing an enlarged plot using **matplotlib** but I fail to add grid, legend in the plot.

```
# Plot outputs
##WORKING PART
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.title('Result Comparison')

##NOT WORKING PART
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.grid(b=True, which='major',axis='both')
plt.legend(('line Expected', 'dot Prediction regressor'),
           loc='upper left')

##WORKING PART
plt.scatter(x_axes, ytestt,  color='black')
plt.plot(x_axes, pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

This is what I am getting with this code
[image]

How should I make the not-working part work and how should I get an image saved?

Comment: Put the not working part after the working part?

Comment: The entire code with 3 section (working-notWorking-Working) is a single code. The 'notWorking' part is compiled but does not affect the plot.

Comment: Because legend doesn't know what to do if nothing is plotted, and your changes to the ticks get overwritten when you first call scatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run into some documentation but mainly benefitted from experimentation,

```
# Plot outputs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Enlarges the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.grid()
plt.title('Result Comparison')

#Its important to label the plot (& scatter) right where you draw them
plt.scatter(x_axes, ytestt,  color='black', label='Expected')
plt.plot(x_axes, pred, color='blue', linewidth=3, label='Predicted Regressor')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')   #The order is important
plt.show()
```

In the docs, I learnt that

- Its better to provide the plot as well as the scatter, their labels **right while drawing them.**
- The **xticks() and yticks()** avoided the grid to show up
- The legend part goes **below** the plotting.